# Web API hangs suddenly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, .net-core

I have a web API in my Blazor project. I have a method that looks like this:

```
  [HttpGet("selected/{userId}/{max}", Name = "GetItems")]
  public IList<ItemDto> GetItems(int userId, int max)
  {
      IList<ItemDto> Items = _itemsDatabaseController.GetItems(userId, max);
      return Items?.Count > 0 ? Items : null;
  }
```

Then I generated client code using NSwag Studio. It all worked fine until some days ago when suddenly my API method hangs after leaving the method (after I step over return and } in debugger just nothing happens).

I read somewhere it might be a problem with JSON serialization if you have nested objects in your DTOs, which I have. But its "just" that in ItemDto I have two other objects, I dont understand why it cant serialize that (if that is the problem at all).

Any ideas why it hangs?

These are my DTO's

```
public class ItemDto
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public CustomerDto CustomerData { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDto
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerSettingsId { get; set; }

    public ObjectDto ObjectData { get; set; }

}

public class ObjectDto
{
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

I am running on .NET Core 3.0. I have not changed the JSON serializer and it should be the default one that is used by Blazor.

Comment: Ok we need to see the ItemDto class along with what ever nested classes. Also we need to know the version of ASP.NET Core you are using and what JSON serializer.

Comment: Edited my question @JonathanAlfaro

Comment: Anyone has any idea on why it hangs?

Comment: Did you place a break point? Also what does the console say? Are there any errors in the console?